# Find a function such that $f(x)>0$, $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$, except exponential functions.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I find a function that the function itself and its first and second derivative are all positive for all x? I don't have a clue, I tried $f(x)=x^2$, but $f'(x)$ have negative value.

Comment: Surely there exist such functions, I found one but it's not elementary: $$f(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{x-t}{1+t^4} dt$$

Comment: Do you consider $f(x) = e^x+1$ an exponential function?

Comment: Polynomials will not work since at least one of $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ will have an odd degree, so will take negative values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: If $g$ is any positive continuous function with finite integral over $(-\infty,x)$ for each $x$ with $\int_{-\infty}^{x} |s||g(s)|ds <\infty$, (example: $g(x)=\frac 1 {1+x^{4}}$) then $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t} g(s)dsdt$ has these prperties.  These gives a large class of such functions.

Comment: $g$ cannot be ANY positive function. It is needed that the integral converges

Comment: @Crostul Yes. I made that clear in my answer.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your answer!

Comment: So ... can we find one of these where $f(x)$ is elementary? I got one with a dilogarithm in it.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $f(x)=a + \int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t} g(s)dsdt$ with a constant $a \ge 0$ are *exactly* the $C^2$ functions with that property.

Comment: @geetha290krm That $g$ doesn't work, the outer integral doesn't converge.

Comment: I think one needs the convergence of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^x sg(s)\,ds $

Answer (score 6):

I tried to find a very elementary and simple function. The best I found is $$f(x)=x + \sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Comment: This function is a great example, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

An elementary example comes from starting with $$f''(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$$ and integrating twice from $-\infty$ to $x$. So then $$f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac12\arctan(x)+\frac12\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$
and $$f(x)=\frac12x\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{4}x+\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Is $e^{e^x}$ exponential?

Details: there are certain operations that from functions with positive derivatives get other functions with positive derivatives:

1. Positive linear combinations ( this would include integral transforms)
2. Composition of functions